# How do i get the value of the checked radio button on react,js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, radio-button

I am making an organized todo list and i would love to have it that if i select any of the radio buttons i can put the input in either of the three options array (array not added in code, in a parent component).
I need a function which can tell me which radio button is checked and how to get the id or value of the checked.

```
const AddTodo = ({ submit, textColor }) => {
  return (
    <div className="displayFlex justCenter">
      <form onSubmit={submit}>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="newTask"
            id="inp"
            placeholder="Enter New Task..."
          />
          <input
            style={{ color: textColor }}
            className="btn"
            type="submit"
            value="Add Task"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
            <input type="radio" id="todo" name="radioButton" value="toDo" />
            <label>To do</label>
          </span>
          <span>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="progress"
              name="radioButton"
              value="inProgress"
            />
            <label>In Progress</label>
          </span>
          <span>
            <input type="radio" id="done" name="radioButton" value="done" />
            <label>Done</label>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddTodo;
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your submit function, or another function which you call inside submit, you can get the value of checked radio button.

```
   function submit(event) {
     [].forEach.call(event.target.elements, function(ele) {
      if (ele.checked) {
        console.log(ele.value); // get the checked radio button's value
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Here is a working [stackblitz url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-m5z41g?file=src/App.js)